# 10 records per keyword SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a relevant search system

so.. first time display the posts with exact match title

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword match%' LIMIT 50
```

after and what i want if it's possible to show 10 records per keyword

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword%' OR `title` LIKE '%match%' LIMIT 10
```

but 10 records for each keyword

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` :

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword%' LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I doubt if this is what she wants o.o. It will show duplicate records as well. I suggest you use UNION ALL

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenge because some posts may match both conditions.  In fact, your first 50 will probably be returned as matches for the other keywords, unless you specifically avoid that.

This may do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword match%' LIMIT 0, 50
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE title like '%keyword%' and title not like '%match%' limit 0, 10
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE title not like '%keyword%' and title like '%match%' limit 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword match%' LIMIT 0,10
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` LIKE '%keyword%' OR `title` LIKE '%match%' LIMIT 0,10
```